# Estimate signal-to-noise ratios by regression

Tags: regression, measurement-error

Suppose we need to measure $y^*_i$ where $i=1,...,n$. We have two independent noisy measurements, $y_{1i}=y_i^*+\xi_i$ and $y_{2i}=y_i^*+\eta_i$, where $\textrm{Cov}(\eta_i,y_i^*)=\textrm{Cov}(\xi_i,y_i^*)=\textrm{Cov}(\eta_i,\xi_i)=0$. We hope to understand how reliable or noisy the first measurement is. Propose a linear regression to estimate the ratio $\lambda=\frac{\text{Var}(y_i^*)}{\text{Var}(y_i^*)+\text{Var}(\xi_i)}$.

I don't fully understand the problem. Should we propose $y_{1i}=\beta y_{2i}+\alpha$ to estimate $\lambda$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We propose a linear regression model: $y_{2i}=\beta y_{1i} + \alpha$ where
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta&=\frac{\mathrm{Cov}(y_{1i},y_{2i})}{\mathrm{Var}(y_{i1})}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{Cov}(y_i^*+\xi_i,y_i^*+\eta_i)}{\mathrm{Var}(y_{i1})}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{E}[(y_i^*+\xi_i)(y_i^*+\eta_i)]-\mathbb{E}[(y_i^*+\xi_i)]\mathbb{E}[(y_i^*+\eta_i)]}{\mathbb{E}[(y_i^*+\xi_i)^2]-\mathbb{E}[y_i^*+\xi_i]^2}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{Var}(y_i^*)+\mathrm{Cov}(\xi_i,y_i^*) +\mathrm{Cov}(\eta_i,y_i^*) +\mathrm{Cov}(\xi_i,\eta_i)}{\mathrm{Var}(y_i^*)+\mathrm{Var}(\xi_i)+2\mathrm{Cov}(y_i^*,\xi_i)}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{Var}(y_i^*)}{\mathrm{Var}(y_i^*)+\mathrm{Var}(\xi_i)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, we have

$$\hat{\lambda}=\frac{1}{\hat{\beta}}=\frac{\sum_{i}^n (y_{1i}-\bar{y}_1)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_{1i}-\bar{y}_1)(y_{2i}-\bar{y}_2)},$$
where $\bar{y}_1=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_{1i} $ and $\bar{y}_2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_{2i}$.